# Button won't align left on all resolutions

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I have created a form with contact form 7, here's the code I generated:

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left;"><label>
    [textarea* your-message placeholder"messsage"] </label></div>

<div style="width:50%;float:right;"><label> 
    [text* your-name placeholder"name*"] </label></div>

<div style="width:50%;float:right;"><label> 
    [text* company-name placeholder"company's name"] </label></div>

<div style="width:50%;float:right;"><label> 
    [tel* tel-783 id:tel-783 class:tel-783 placeholder"phone*"] </label></div>

<div style="width:50%;float:right;"><label> 
[email email-731 id:email-731 class:email-731 placeholder"email"]

<label> [submit id:button-22 class:button-22 "send"]</label>
```

I have tried to make the button align left and remain there at the same place no matter what resolution the screen is, but both float: left and position: fixed didn't work for me. Actually, position:fixed made my button disappear so I used relative instead. Here's the current CSS:

```css
input[type='text'],
input[type='tel'],
input[type="email"] {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: heebo;
  color: #001a71 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #001a71 !important;
  font-size: 1.563em !important;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -30px !important;
  margin-top: -28px !important;
  position: relative !important min-width: 190px;
}

textarea {
  height: 190px;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: heebo;
  color: #001a71 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #001a71 !important;
  font-size: 1.563em !important;
  margin-top: -4px !important;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  position: relative !important min-width: 190px;
}

#button-22 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #4a5ba8;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #4a5ba8;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 -13.2em;
  position: relative min-width:43.446 px max-width: 43.446px;
  !important float: left !important;
}

.contact-form-wrapper input[type=”submit”] float: left !important;

}
#button-22:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #4a5ba8;
  border: 1px solid #4a5ba8;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative min-width:43.446 px max-width: 43.446px float: !important;
}
```

[image: Here's a demonstration of how I want it to look]

Can someone please tell me how to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute;` and use the `left` and `bottom` attributes to position the button.

Example code based on your CSS:

```
#button-22 {
text-transform: uppercase;
background: #4a5ba8;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #4a5ba8;
font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: 300;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
padding: 10px;
margin:0 -13.2em;
position: absolute;
left: 0 /* adjust this as required */
bottom: 0 /* adjust this as required */
min-width:43.446 px;
max-width: 43.446px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Please make sure you put the `;` at the end of every CSS property that you define.